# Redesigning website mock-up

Tags: mockup

I have to redesign a website and provide mock-ups. I was given the link to the live website but i was wondering how will i go about creating this mock-up? I make my own original mock-ups from scratch.

This is the first time i will base it on redesigning a website that exist. Do i screenshot an image of the page and crop sections? Or try and mimic it from scratch except maybe the logo?

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1, working with your sketches:**
Create a simple mock up with Balsamiq to show your client your rough vision of the site. After discussing the mock ups you can expand the mock ups with Photoshop.

**Case 2, working with the current site:**
If your client wants to keep the current structure of the site, you can go into Firebug and modify the CSS files.

Comment: Hi user3186429, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!